# GCC cross compiling - undefined reference to `__strtof_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE'

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, undefined-reference

I'm cross-compiling a project using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc on Ubuntu using make.
Linker issues the following error:

/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/libm.so.6; undefined reference to `__strtod_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE'

Any help would be appreciated.

nm -AD /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/libm.so.6 | grep __strtod_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE produces the following resutl:
libm.so.6:    U __strtod_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE

Comment: That seems odd, but there's not enough information presented to diagnose the issue.  Or for me to do , anyway.  We generally expect a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you for your comment, what information do you need to help?

Comment: How about following my link to an explanation, and advice for producing the wanted details?